# How to refer to a website with section tags (HTML)

Tags: html, html-select

If you have

```
 <select>
   <option value="val1">Teemo bot</option>
   <option value="val2">Teemo mid</option>
   <option value="val3">Akali mid</option>
 </select>
```

How do I make it, when you click on one, it transfers you to another site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you might want to use on change, since you are unable to select a option if first click redirects.

```
 <select onchange="javascript:document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
   <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
   <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I tried it on my site but I just goes to a site "undefined". http://prntscr.com/54pzrc

Comment: my bet, the typical jQuerish thing was going on.